# How to recover all the elements of a registry key? (last write time, type, value, name …) Is this the right method?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registrykey

I would like to recover all the elements of a registry key.  the methods of the windows API RegOpenEX and RegEnumKeyEx.But I'm not sure this is the right way to do that. Here is an example of my code, so should these two methods be used to retrieve this information?

```
HKEY RegHkey;
Long RC=0;
DWORD a=0;
DWORD TMP=255;
FILETIME filetime;
LPWSTR lpName=nullptr;
LPWSTR lpClass=nullptr;
DWORD cchClasss=0;

RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\",0,KEY_READ,&RegHkey);

while(RC != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
{
  RC=RegEnumKeyEx(RegHkey, a, lpName, &TMP, nullptr, lpClass, &cchClass, &filetime);
   if(RC==ERROR_SUCCESS)
   {
      std::cout<<"type= "<<cchClass<<std::endl;
     //etc...

   }
   a++;
}
```

if RC==ERROR_SUCCESS I would like to retrieve the type, value, and last_write_time.... Is this the right method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, almost everything is wrong in this code.

> ```
> LPWSTR lpName=nullptr;
> LPWSTR lpClass=nullptr;
> ```

Whenever the documentation for a function parameter says something like "*A pointer to a buffer*", you are required to provide a buffer, that *you* have allocated.

```
// The {} brackets zero-initialize the buffers.
wchar_t szName[255]{};
wchar_t szClass[255]{};
```

> ```
> DWORD TMP=255;
> DWORD cchClasss=0;
> ```

Setting `cchClass` to zero is wrong. You have to tell the function, how big your buffers actually are (how many characters including '\0' it can store there). The variable `TMP` has no meaningful name, `cchName` will be more consistent:

```
// No need to hardcode the array size.
DWORD cchName  = ARRAYSIZE(szName);
DWORD cchClass = ARRAYSIZE(szClass);
```

> ```
> RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\",0,KEY_READ,&RegHkey);
> ```

Missing a check for the success of the function. Opening a registry key can fail for a wide variety of reasons, e. g. not enough permissions:

```
DWORD res = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\",0,KEY_READ,&RegHkey);
if(res == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    // do something with the registry key
}
```

> ```
> while(RC != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
> ```

You have an endless loop when `RegEnumKeyEx` fails for other reasons than finishing enumeration. Correct condition would be `RC == ERROR_SUCCESS`.

> ```
>   RC=RegEnumKeyEx(RegHkey, a, lpName, &TMP, nullptr, lpClass, &cchClass, &filetime);
> ```

The children of the registry key `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\` are values, so you have to use `RegEnumValueW()` instead.

Make sure you also call `RegCloseKey()` once you are done with the registry key.

Comment: If I understood your answer, i have to use RegOpenKeyEx, RegEnumKeyEx and RegEnumValue? or just RegOpenKeyEx and RegEnumKeyEx ?

Comment: @Tom13000 only `RegOpenKeyEx`, `RegEnumValue`

Comment: ok but I canot recover last write time with RegEnumValue ...? The parameter PFILETIME lpftLastWriteTime is not in the RegEnumValue function ...

Comment: @Tom13000 Correct, last write time is only available for registry keys, but not for registry values.

Comment: if I understood, I have to use RegOpenKeyEx and RegEnumValue for recover value and type and I have to use RegEnumKeyEx for last write time ?

Comment: @Tom13000 Last write time is only stored for registry *keys*, which in your case is `L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\"`. A registry may have children which are *keys* or *values* (or a mixture of both). In this case, we only have *values*, so you can't get last write time of the individual entries.

Comment: Do you have an example please of these functions because I do not understand everything ...

Comment: @Tom13000 Examples are linked in the official documentation.